# Error 'You have not defined a default connection` while connecting multiple database using mongoengine connect()

Tags: django, mongodb

I have two apps which connects to the same mongodb database using mongoengine. one of the Apps is working fine but when I open the second App it throws an error `"A different connection with alias 'default' was already registered. Use disconnect() first"`.

Then I changed the alias in the `connect` function of one Apps as connect(alias='default2', db='variome'). now it throws the error `You have not defined a default connection`

Can someone please help to fix this

Answer (score 0):

The connections are globally set in `MongoEngine` ([doc](https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/connecting.html#connecting-to-mongodb)) and it doesn't let you register 2 (different) connection on the same alias.

I'm not sure what you call "app" here but they seem to be part of the same process, meaning if both of your app connect to the same database, you don't need to register the connection twice, just register it once, where the process (flask or whatever it is) is bootstrapped.

If you want to use different alias, you need to bind the Document classes to that alias (otherwise they bind to 'alias' by default, which is why you get that error). ([doc](https://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/connecting.html#documents-defined-in-different-database))